# Telnet from Linux to Android devices

Tags: linux, connectify

I am attempting to telnet from my Ubuntu commandline to my Android phone and pad using the following syntax:

```
> telnet 192.168.0.4 

Trying 192.168.0.4... 

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

But, I get that error message above when I try both devices.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you running a telnet server on the Android device? Which one?

Comment: I am just executing telnet from Ubuntu on my laptop

Comment: `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl`

Answer (score 10):

Android does not include a telnet daemon. Use the included android debug bridge (meant for development or power users). It comes with the official SDK ( http://developer.android.com/sdk/ ).

- Install both "tools" packages
- Enable USB debugging in your phone settings
- run `./platform-tools/adb shell` in yor sdk folder (needs approprate USB rights for your phone)

You then have a local shell on your phone.

If you definitely need access over network install an ssh server app ([search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ssh%20server&c=apps) play store for SSHDroid or QuickSSHd). You might want a *secure* shell server on a mobile device that connects to multiple maybe unsafe networks like public hotspots.

Comment: For the record adb can work wirelessly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's however not very secure and needs to be switched on after every boot therefore (that's why I omitted it in my original post)

Comment: It's like a bomb waiting to blow up :) I'm pretty sure that's why they make you enable it after reboots.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the former answer is installing [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en). Its really nice, but read the description to consider stuff like:

> NB: This app CANNOT be installed onto the SDCard because you do not get 'Execute' permissions on that mount. It must run in this app's private memory on the device [Also much more secure]. You can of course still read / write to the SDCard and store files there. ALSO - once extracted it takes up about 100MB. You have been warned.

Comment: LOL, has even a telnetd included, but comes with a hefty price: 32MB. It's also a full Development Kit for  Android, you might better try this tinier app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm (it comes included with many ROMs)